# What's this class name called in Bootstrap 3 showing this textbox effect?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, angular-ui-bootstrap

When you have a textbox and you want to display this effect in Bootstamp 3.  What's the classname called for this?  (blue bar at left corner)

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's called `bs-callout` class with 6 styles:

*`default, primary, success, info, warning, danger.`*

See it on this [**codepen**](http://codepen.io/chrisdpratt/pen/IAymB/) example.